# Touch up Plaster/White Cement

Tags: repair, walls

My windows contractor replaced my windows casement. Once they install the new one, they patch up the wall/plaster it with white cement.

However, I'm not satisfied with the work, they are so uneven and unsightly (see picture).

What's the best way to fix it?

[image: Ugly Plaster]

Comment: If you are planning on adding a jamb extension and trim, all of the ugly should cover.

Comment: nothing will be there.... so i want to clean or trim them

Comment: That flange along the bottom of the window is designed to go under a trim piece. You need two trim pieces, one covering this flange and another one spanning the interior edge of that trim piece out to the wallboard around the window.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to trim them with 240 grit paper + orbital sander. :)

Comment: Please accept your answer to resolve the question.